# Finding the header in a large txt file pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a large file with a few million lines. The first 300+ (variable number) lines contain info about the file, and then there is a header line before the data. I do not know what line the header is on, but I know what it starts with. Here is a sample of My data:

```
#This File contains some cool suff
#We will see what line the header is on
#Maybe it is in this line
#CHROM POS ID 
1 100 17
2 200 18
2 300 18
```

The header line is the `#CHROM POS ID`

Here is what I have tried but it returns `list index out of range`:

```
database = pd.read_table(infile, header=[num for num,line in enumerate(infile) if line.startswith("#CHROM")])
```

I think I have naively assumed that `pd.read_table` operates in the same way as `with open()` and that may have worked. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is `infile` a string or a file object?

Comment: Unless the first column's name isn't `#CHROM` (including the `#`) then this is not a valid csv file. If the header row has the `#` removed (by whatever means, preprocessing for example) you can simply set `comment='#'` in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). If the first column's name is indeed `#CHROM` then better choose another character since this doesn't let you distinguish from the comment lines (again, unless these don't start with `# ` (additional space here) then you could set `comment='# '`).

Comment: I didn’t call the file a csv file. I called it a text file. And the first few hundred lines have the comment format but so does the header. Which is why I asked the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to be successful for my particular application of finding the header in a large text file. First, write a function to read line by line until the match is found:

```
def headerFinder(infile):
    with open(infile) as f:
        for num,line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
                return num
```

This first block of code will enumerate your lines in file and find the matching line, and you can then actually pass the function call to the `pd.read_table()` function as follows:

```
def tableReader(infile, *argv):
    df = pd.read_table(infile, header=headerFinder(infile), usecols=argv)
    return df
```

Because my infile is large, there are also 300+ columns, so I found this to be a good way to pass a variable number of headers, example of function call:

```
tableDF = tableReader(input_file, '#CHROM', 'POS', 'ID', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INFO')
```

So my whole little program is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

input_file = sys.argv[1]

def headerFinder(infile):
    with open(infile) as f:
        for num,line in enumerate(f):
            if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
                return num

def tableReader(infile, *argv):
    df = pd.read_table(infile, header=headerFinder(infile), usecols=argv)
    return df

tableDF = tableReader(input_file, '#CHROM', 'POS', 'ID', 'REF', 'ALT', 'INFO')

#to view as test of success

(tableDF[:10]).to_csv('./test_table', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: just saw that it is a text file

set a variable as headerrow,

```
lineno = 0
for line in infile.readlines():
    if line.startswith('#CHROM'):
        headerrow = lineno
    lineno += 1
```

then when you bring in the file you could do something like pd.read_table('my_file.txt', header = headerrow) plus whatever other parameters you need.

Comment: you might need to define the separator, depending on how the table is structured